# Unable to set ImageURL after firebase call using uploadBytes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Why is `imageURL` always `null`? `uploadBytes` definitely returns an `imageURL` string after the image is uploaded to the Cloud Storage of Firebase. I set `imageURL` using React state before `addDoc` is called. But I am able to get the imageURL using console.log(imageURL). Is it related to promises or async/await?

```
const uploadPhoto = (upload) => {
    if (upload === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/inventory/${upload[0].uid}`);
    uploadBytes(imageRef, upload[0].originFileObj)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
      })
      .then((downloadURL) => {
        setImageURL(downloadURL);
        console.log("Download URL", downloadURL);
      });
  };
  delete addInventoryDetailsFormData.upload;
  Promise.all([
    uploadPhoto(upload),
    addDoc(inventoryCollectionRef, {
      ...inventoryFormData,
      ...addInventoryDetailsFormData,
      createdTime: Date.now(),
      region: User.region ? User.region : "Global",
      createdBy: User.username,
      roleId: User.roleId,
      imageURL: imageURL,
    }),
  ])
    .then(() => navigate("/app/news-manage/draft"))
    .then(() => message.success("Inventory successfully added", 5));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question with a clarification of what "But I am able to console it out of the image URL" means. A complete rewrite of that sentence is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that:

1. The upload has finished before you request the download URL
2. Ensure that the download URL has been set before you try to write it to the database

Your code does #1, but it doesn't do #2. Using `Promise.all()` doesn't help here, since `setImageURL` itself is asynchronous too - and worse: one that doesn't return a promise you can wait on.

Instead of passing the download URL through React's state (which is meant to use for data you want to render in its UI), consider simply using a local variable and return value.

Something like this:

```
const uploadPhoto = (upload) => {
  if (upload === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/inventory/${upload[0].uid}`);
  return uploadBytes(imageRef, upload[0].originFileObj) // 
    .then((snapshot) => {
      return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
    })
    .then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log("Download URL", downloadURL);
      return downloadURL; // 
    });
};

uploadPhoto(upload).then((downloadURL) => { // 
  addDoc(inventoryCollectionRef, {
    ...inventoryFormData,
    ...addInventoryDetailsFormData,
    createdTime: Date.now(),
    region: User.region ? User.region : "Global",
    createdBy: User.username,
    roleId: User.roleId,
    imageURL: downloadURL, // 
  }),
])
```

The solution from the author of this question.

```
const saveInventory = () => {
  try {
    const inventoryFormData = inventoryForm.getFieldValue();
    const addInventoryDetailsFormData = addInventoryDetailsForm.current.getFieldValue();
    const upload = addInventoryDetailsFormData.upload;
    console.log(upload);
    if (upload === undefined) {
      delete addInventoryDetailsFormData.upload;
      addDoc(inventoryCollectionRef, {
        ...inventoryFormData,
        ...addInventoryDetailsFormData,
        createdTime: Date.now(),
        region: User.region ? User.region : "Global",
        createdBy: User.username,
        roleId: User.roleId,
        imageURL: null,
      })
        .then(() => navigate("/app/news-manage/draft"))
        .then(() => message.success("Inventory successfully added", 5));
    } else {
      const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/inventory/${upload[0].uid}`);
      uploadBytes(imageRef, upload[0].originFileObj)
        .then((snapshot) => {
          return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
        })
        .then((downloadURL) => {
          delete addInventoryDetailsFormData.upload;
          addDoc(inventoryCollectionRef, {
            ...inventoryFormData,
            ...addInventoryDetailsFormData,
            createdTime: Date.now(),
            region: User.region ? User.region : "Global",
            createdBy: User.username,
            roleId: User.roleId,
            imageURL: downloadURL,
          })
            .then(() => navigate("/app/news-manage/draft"))
            .then(() => message.success("Inventory successfully added", 5));
        });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  };
```

Comment: If I use uploadPhoto.then(...) there's an error when there is no photo uploaded.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, and it's hard to troubleshoot your changes in comments. --- Does the explanation I gave in my answer on why your code doesn't work make sense? Do the changes in the code I gave make sense? And does it make sense how those changes should then address the problem?

Comment: Yes I had tried your method but the uploadPhoto method will always return only after the addDoc is being called. When I put .then() after upload photo I will get this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then'). Your solution make sense but seem like it is not working well

Comment: I managed to do it by changing the structure a bit. Thanks, Frank, for explaining that issue. I edited the code to solve my issue.